# How to not reload screen on react-navigation when going back to it on the stack?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Question: I have this screen and whenever I do anything but use `props.navigation.navigate()` and do the slide back it causes a reload on the screen. I want a way to go back to the screen and not cause a reload by using a button on another screen on the stack

So I have this screen

[image]

And if do `props.navigation.navigate("subscreen")` I get what I want when I go back to the screen by sliding it doesn't reload the page as seen below:

[image]

However when I do `props.navigation.goBack()` when a button is clicked on the other page it causes a reload when it comes back as seen below:

[image]

So how do I go back to a screen without sliding back to it and not cause a reload?